# Duality between tangent and cotangent bundles

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles, duality-theorems

Given a smooth manifold $M$, the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ is dual to the tangent bundle $TM$ "fiberwise", i.e. $\forall x\in M$, $T^*_x(M)=(T_x(M))^*$.

Now, if the manifold is a vector space, then the tangent space is a topological vector space, and the cotangent bundle is homeomorphic to the topological dual of the tangent bundle, i.e. $T^*M \simeq (TM)^*$. My question is then two-fold:

- Is the last assertion true (modulo some additional hypothesis that I forgot)? If yes, is it true in general for Fréchet manifolds or only for finite dimensional manifolds?
- Are there situations other than this trivial one where it could be true? I would be interested on sufficient (and possibly necessary) conditions on $M$ such that: $TM$ is a topological vector space, and $T^*M \simeq (TM)^*$ (where $\simeq$ stands for homeomorphism).

Comment: First, the tangent bundle of a vector space is always trivial. Second, surely $T^*M \not= (TM)^*$ because they are different objects; do you mean diffeomorphic? homeomorphic? vector space isomorphic? Third, in order to make sense of this question you need to provide (a) your definition of the smooth structure on the dual of a (smooth) vector space (b) your definition of an infinite dimensional manifold. (I don't intend to sound rude, just concise)

Comment: @J.Loreaux For the first comment, I suspected that. For the second, homeomorphic is more than sufficient, for I am only interested in a topological information. For the third, I do not understand exactly point (a), i.e. what do you intend by smooth structure, and why would you need it to eventually prove a topological duality. As for point (b), let's say a Banach manifold. I would be interested on a "locally convex manifold" (a manifold modelled on a locally convex top vec space), but I do not know if it exists. I edited the text accordingly.

Comment: Topological manifolds do not have tangent spaces, much less tangent bundles.

Comment: What is the topology that you put on the dual, in case of the infinite dimension case a vector space is not always isomorphic to its dual endowed with the weak topology as shows Banach Alaoglu

Comment: @MikeMiller Ok, so let's stick to finite dimensional ones; or infinite dimensional ones that do allow for a tangent bundle to be defined.

Comment: What I said isn't an infinite-dimensional quirk. Topological manifolds are not things that have a tangent bundle. Smooth manifolds (topological manifolds with an additional *smooth structure*) do. This is what J. Loreaux was pointing out in (3). The only question is what one means by infinite-dimensional smooth manifold. The weakest kind of topological vector space you can use for this is Frechet, where derivatives are still a thing that are defined.

Comment: In the finite dimensional case, just take a metric, it defines an isomorphism between the tangent and the cotangent bundle

Comment: @MikeMiller Ok, I see. But given a smooth (Fréchet) manifold, then the tangent and cotangent bundles are topological spaces, or is it not always true? If it is true, then the question as it is edited now should be ok...